# database relationship scheme MySQL - profiles

Tags: mysql, database, relationship

I want to create an application, and before starting to program, I would like to hear your professional advice and recommendations on the basic model as I had it in mind.
Sorry for the fact that I did not draw the structure in text, but this seemed like the clearest way to present my case.

[image]

The situation is like this:

- Users can make friends;
- Users can create a profile for one or more entities such as bars, restaurants, event organizers or shops. It is possible that the number of these main categories will increase (and there will also be sub-categories within these main-cats). When creating an entity profile, profile_tbl, owner_tbl and bar/organizer_tbl are immediately updated, and the user is automatically assigned the "root" user role status. I suppose that this has to be done via a mySQL transaction;
- Different profiles have different characteristics: bars, restaurants, events, shops are somehow comparable, yet they have a lot of different characteristics that will be reflected in their profile. Therefore, I have splitted them up into separate tables. After entity profile creation, users can configure their entity profile;
- A user can only be the owner for the same owned profile (bar, resto, event, shop) once (which is why I created a composite PK in the owner_tbl);
- A user with a profile and 'root' user role status (the founder of the place) can grant co-management to other users. 
  Based on user role, users will be able to perform certain actions and have certain viewing rights.

If you think it is no good, can you share with me on the why? Please let me know what is wrong with the picture, as the rest of my development efforts would be in vain.
I'm quite sure that you have an idea of where this application is going.
If you have any further recommendations, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating seprate tables for each event i.e. bar,  organizer etc, create just 1 table profile_details (or events) which will hold all events. In this table add col named event_description. This is important as in ur current design to find what event a profile belongs u hv to validate against each and every event table. Other than this on a high level ur design looks good.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply. Do you mean that I should aggregate all detail information about bars, event organizers, shops etc into one single table? I'm afraid that this will overload the table as much detailed and unrelated entity typical information would be contained in the table or related by the table towards other child tables. Eg. an event organizer may create a lineup of artists, having artist profiles (relation to the organizer table), but it has nothing really to do with for example a shop. There will be many example like this. What's your view on this topic?

Comment: I strongly believe that as long as all events share similar characteristics they should be in single table. By overloading do u mean performance issues? Indexes can be created to take care of it later on but initially design has to be right. Once again as i mentioned in my answer if in ur current design i give u a profile id, how will u determine which event it belongs without scaning each and every event tables u create. Moreover in future if new events would come u will end up creating new tables which is not right.

Comment: +1 Ok, I see your point. Similarities can be gathered in the same table. By overloading the table, I actually meant overloading a table with a lot of unrelated information -> but it seems like it's important to identify the shared with the individual characteristics of each entity. And I see what you mean; for reading profile info, it will only scan one table instead of many, except when there is a request for information that would be typical for an entity. Do I see this the right way? I'll accept your answer tomorrow, if noone else opposes further objections to the scheme.

Comment: Yes. But again as u said there can be some unrelated details for events. For that also I would suggest to have 1 more table (again only 1 more) for all events unrelated details in rows for each event instead of putting them in cols. So new table might call as EventMoreDetails with cols eventid, characterisid, characteristic detail and other cols.

Comment: Ok thanks Nitin. The principle is clear, I'll look into that!